# How to manually delete a Job on Hudson

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jobs

Hudson is configured to retain last 5 builds only. But i see some old builds still present and can't delete them from UI. When i try to delete it does nothing.

Please suggest some manual way to clean such jobs.. Thanks

Comment: FYI it's called a build, not a job.  Title is inaccurate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to `Hudson_Home/jobs/<Job_Name>/builds`. For each build folders will be present in the following format `2014-02-07_16-21-15`. Delete the older/unwanted folders and go to Hudson Dashboard, Hudson >> Manage Hudson >> Reload Configuration from Disk